# Remove an element from an interface collection

Tags: c#, collections, interface

I want to use this interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
 int Id { get; set; }
 string Name { get; set; }
 ICollection<IBar> IBars{ get; set; } //association with another entity
}
```

My implementation is as follows:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars{ get; set; }

//Interface implementation
 public ICollection<IBar> IBars
        {
            get
            {
                return Bars.Cast<IBar>().ToList();
                //or return new List<ICardInquiry>(CardsInquiries);
            }

            set
            {
                if (value is ICollection<IBar>)
                    Bars= ((ICollection<IBar>)value).Cast<Bar>().ToList();
                else
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
}
```

This implementation prevents me to remove an element from the collection:

```
IFoo iFoo = MyIFooFactory.CreateIFoo();
IBar iBar = iFooIBars.First();
iFoo.IBars.Remove(iBar);
```

This will NOT remove the element! I do understand why. The reason is my interface collection getter, which is again as follows:

```
public ICollection<IBar> IBars
        {
            get
            {
                return Bars.Cast<IBar>().ToList();
                //or return new List<ICardInquiry>(CardsInquiries);
            }
          ...
         }
```

IBars returns a new list so the element is removed from the returned list and not from the original collection (Bars).

How can I get out of this situation?
I really don't want IFoo to know about Bar and to only manimpulate IBar.

Comment: Any reason `Bars` can't just be `ICollection<IBar>`?

Comment: @ Loocid : Bar and Foo are entity Framework model classes.
If I decclare IBars as ICollection<IBar> instead of  ICollection<Bar>, EF will not set my navigation property based on the database population.

Answer (score 0):

The items in `Bars` are not removed because you are returning a *new* list in the getter of `IBars`:

```
return Bars.Cast<IBar>().ToList(); // ToList creates a new list.
```

You can't really convert a `ICollection<Bar>` to a `ICollection<IBar>` without creating something new because the generic parameter in `ICollection` is invariant.

The only thing you could do here is to add a `Remove` method in `IFoo`:

```
 void RemoveIBar(IBar ibar);
```

And implement it like this in `Foo`:

```
public void RemoveIBar(IBar ibar) {
    if (ibar is Bar) {
        Bars.Remove((Bar)ibar);
    } else {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Also the check in the setter of `IBars` is redundant.

Obviously, that's not type-safe. A more type-safe to do this would be to make `IFoo` take a generic parameter `TBar` and have a `ICollection<TBar>`. `Foo` can then implement `IFoo<Bar>`:

```
public interface IFoo<TBar> where TBar: IBar
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    ICollection<TBar> TBars{ get; set; } //association with another entity
}

public class Foo : IFoo<Bar>
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars{ get; set; }

}
```

But I guess that counts as `IFoo` knowing about `Bar`.